# Integrating CSV person data on Google Maps through Bluemix?

Tags: csv, maps, ibm-cloud, ibm-watson

I am working on a project with a large CSV file that containes the location and movement of users. I would like to place this on a custom map in Google Maps via bluemix and use Bluemix Services to explore the data.

The primary goals are:

1. Getting the CSV data on the custom Google map. When running, the data should progress in time and show the movement of users.
2. Making the CSV points cluster for UX. (so that points that are near each other would stack together)

My primary question is how to get started on this. Do you reccommend i work on this locally and then connect Bluemix to my project or can i create all of this in Bluemix. I would much prefer the last option if possible.

If you have any suggestions to Watson Services or other Bluemix Features that may improve the app this is also greatly appreciated

Thank you for your time. 
Ps. I realize Google Maps integrates best with Java Script. Do you recommend converting the CSV to Json when working with Bluemix?

Answer (score 0):

This is a quite broad question and maybe not well suited for stackoverflow (stackoverflow is not a discussion forum, it is a competition of what answer is the most accurate one for a very strict question) so maybe this is a question for https://developer.ibm.com/answers/ instead.

That said, bluemix works well with js, java, ruby, python, go, php, etc (probably js and java better than the others) so I'd go in this direction. Also, I think you should investigate bluemix geospatial analytics (https://console.ng.bluemix.net/catalog/services/geospatial-analytics/) for your application.

For data storage, I suggest you to take a look on cloudant (https://console.ng.bluemix.net/catalog/services/cloudant-nosql-db/) which is a very popular option in bluemix and suits well for most cloud apps. If you want to take a more traditional approach, you can also consider a relational db such as DB2 (https://console.ng.bluemix.net/catalog/services/ibm-db2-on-cloud/)